# How to correctly configure volumes with docker-compose for a Django app using postgres?

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have a dockerized Django application using Postgresql. Everything runs find until I add volumes to the docker-compose file so I can have persistent data storage for the DB.

docker-compose.yml :

```
version: "3"

services: 
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    command: > 
      sh -c "python manage.py wait_for_db &&
             python manage.py migrate &&
             python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_NAME=app
      - DB_USER=postgres
      - DB_PASS=dbpassword

    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:10-alpine
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=app
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=dbpassword
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

Error Message here:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
app_1  |    Is the server running on host "db" (172.26.0.2) and accepting
app_1  |    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
app_1  |
recipe-api_app_1 exited with code 1
db_1   | 2019-08-31 22:52:35.969 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
db_1   | 2019-08-31 22:52:35.969 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
db_1   | 2019-08-31 22:52:35.972 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db_1   | 2019-08-31 22:52:36.042 UTC [18] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2019-08-31 22:41:04 UTC
db_1   | 2019-08-31 22:52:36.055 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Once you add the volumes for the docker-compose I keep getting this error and without volumes everything runs fine.

EDIT : wait_for_db command :

```
   def handle(self, *args, **options):
        """Handle the command"""
        self.stdout.write('Waiting for database...')
        db_conn = None
        while not db_conn:
            try:
                db_conn = connections['default']
            except OperationalError:
                self.stdout.write('Database unavailable, waiting 1 second...')
                time.sleep(1)

        self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS('Database available!'))
```

Comment: That looks like the database is starting up correctly, but the application demands a connection before it's ready; I'd debug why your `wait_for_db` isn't.

Comment: @DavidMaze I have edited the question to add the `wait_for_db` command I have, I don't understand why it would work with out volumes added but not when I add the volume for postgres

Comment: @DavidMaze It was an issue with the `wait_for_db` script , fixed it thanks